# How do I pass username and password from Excel VBA to batch file

Tags: windows, vba, excel

I am trying to pass a username and password from Excel VBA to a batch file. I am able to pass the values however, the batch file echoes the combined values of username and password:

```
    filepath = "C:\Users\testfiles\filetest.bat " & username & password
```

In the batch file, I set username = %1 and password =%2. but it appears that username is showing the concatenation of both arguments, and password is not receiving the input.

Answer (score 0):

insert a space between username and password

```
filepath = "C:\Users\testfiles\filetest.bat " & username & " " & password
```